# Teradata regexp_replace to eliminate specific special characters

Tags: regex, teradata, regexp-replace

I imported a file that contains email addresses (email_source). I need to join this table to another, using this field but it contains commas (,) and double quotes (") before and after the email address (eg. "johnsmith@gmail.com,","). I want to replace all commas and double quotes with a space.

What is the correct syntax in teradata?

Comment: So for your example you want ` johnsmith@gmail.com    `, yes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do this:

`REGEXP_REPLACE(email_source, '[,"]', ' ',1,0,i)`

Breakdown:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(email_source, -- sourcestring
'[,"]', -- regexp
' ', --replacestring
1, --startposition
0, -- occurrence, 0 = all
'i' -- match -> case insensitive
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a regex for this, a simple oTranslate should be more efficient:

```
oTranslate(email_source, ',"', '  ')
```